# How to boot 32-bit Linux kernel on 64-bit UEFI system without CSM

Tags: ubuntu, grub, uefi, bios, 32bit

I have a system on which I *have* to run a 32-bit Linux kernel, as it needs to interact with obsolete hardware which only have a 32-bit driver available. Changing the driver is not feasible.

The Dell machine I am trying to accomplish this on does not have a CSM (legacy boot support) that works with internal drives.
 (It only has M.2 NVME internal drive slots)

I installed Grub 64-bit UEFI (from an Ubuntu live disk), and it detects my "legacy" Linux instance (on the same disk, if it's important. GPT-formatted.), however when I select that 32-bit kernel from the "legacy" Linux install, Grub gives me an error:
`Kernel doesn't support 64-bit CPUs.`

Can anyone shed some light on this or point me in the right direction?
I was under the [impression](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Supported-kernels) that it was no problem for Grub to boot a different architecture kernel.

Comment: What is the version of the kernel?

Comment: You might hit other issues later anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610442/how-could-32bit-kernel-read-efivars-from-64bit-uefi

Comment: What about virtualising the 32-bit OS under a 64-bit hypervisor? Then pass-through your physical device.

Comment: @roaima I have another environment that I also have to virtualize on the same system so I had hoped to avoid virtualizing this one, but I suppose it looks like the simplest option at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to boot a 32-bit Ubuntu on 64-bit EFI machine with help of package `grub-efi-amd64-signed`, installed via `chroot`.
See the HowTo here (in German): https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Howto/Installation_von_32-Bit_Ubuntu_auf_EFI-System/

Anyway I sometimes have trouble, when GRUB gets updated.

Comment: If there are important steps in the linked HowTo, would you please incorporate them into your answer here? Thank you!

Comment: To my opinion, all steps in the HowTo are important.